# Error: No component factory found for [object Object]

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm stuck.
I know how to usually deal with the problem, but this time I'm stuck.

1) `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

Why the error message says `[object Object]`, instead of specific component?

I know where is the error, I know which code is causing it.
But I do not understand WHY the error occurs and WHY it says `[object Object]`.

2) I have created a component, I have added it to `declarations` and to the `entryCompoents`. Now I am trying to use this component as a modal from another compoent of **the same module**.

I wrote a code:

```
  openModal() {
    const modal = this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: SetLocationModal
    });

    modal.present();
    return false;
  }
```

`<span (click)="openModal()">open modal</span>`

and it fails to execute

Comment: Did the modal need any module to be imported? For eg, if you are using `ngx-bootstrap`, you need to import `NgbModule`

Comment: the modal is the part of the same module

Comment: I have just tested, by creating a fresh new project, said, but it already uses Ionic 4. The ModalController now uses promises, and adjusting the code a little bit makes it working. But it fails for me with Ionic 3

Comment: yes, just tested again, if i start even a blank project using ionic 3, then I get the same error. Command line: 
ionic start MyIonicProject blank --type=ionic-angular

Comment: I've got a working example. I think Ionic 3 can only use Pages a modal content, that a loaded dynamically (lazy-loaded), but cannot use native compoents. Ionic 4 supports this.

Answer (score 2):

As you found out your code works only for ionic v4. Facing the same problem and not wanting to upgrade ionic just yet I found this code working for me:

On opening page:

```
async presentModal() {
    let modal = this.modalController.create(ModalNew);
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    modal.present();
  }
```

modal:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ViewController} from "ionic-angular";

@Component({
  selector: 'new-time',
  templateUrl: 'new.html'
})
export class ModalNew {

  constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
    // componentProps can also be accessed at construction time using NavParams
  }
}
```

modal html

```
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
    <h1 class="title">My Modal title</h1>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content padding>
  </ion-content>
```

This answer is based on: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/modal/ModalController/

Comment: Yes, I was mixed up the Ionic v3 and Ionic v4 versions. The Ionic 3 Modal accepts the component itself, whereas Ionic 4 accepts and object, with a property `component`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of modalCtrl? a MatDialog? or other? I have implemented in previous projects and remember doing 'open' not create

```
  this.modalCtrl.open(RequestCardComponent, {/*any data to pass to the component*/});
```

Comment: The type is ModalController - the Ionic 3 in-built component